# Why is margin-right of ul pushing the text away in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[This code in codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/OJNwwJe?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=d000e1b4abb6219d774a41d78579495c3d575b3e-1600240373-0-AeHn3t-cVcWl7oV5i6YLNHgAgY05-wi6VacSGCXvKXDkQbmH7ycY6fmiJ5OkuzdZFha6HR8-JUxfOXISUGTs8_OzjMyl3jOx98pKuLmt43BkWqb9zxWeXhkYOEqPr85muHIluW5Cbdk8YtFEJUspfzJlTSzjOEOW0tkVzvhu5uZjOXXTExjScjSMHz0KjOo3D4yDB4StuTOia6tmqzS5qVC9pbnedLtlmJ8wSob8wyClz8MXAt62WgY7bpKtLkX48M2cs3RbmgTJ0RsNZbp_rzV_Bz6rpdTePlKuXYx9AFcORXIuGHuRSmbAB9Z_oI9-c2CgAA6NhyYlIaCQum9biIPzY753912p3QVB7oW9YXgT) was shown by @[Simplicius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14036853/simplicius) in a now deleted thread.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

li {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  left-margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>AAAA</li>
  <li>BBBB</li>
</ul>

<p> This is my name. This is my name.This is my name.This is my name.This is my name.</p>

<p> This is my name. This is my name.This is my name.This is my name.This is my name.</p>
```

While this code works, my question is - why does writing `margin-right` in `ul` push the text covered by `p` away?

I am under an impression that margin-right is used to push the object to which it is applied away? In this case it is pushing the unrelated text away. Please explain how does this work.

Comment: margin-right does what it says on the tin - it increases the margin on the right hand side, its got nothing to do with pushing things away. The UL is floated left, so the text slides up to the right then the margin-right just puts space between them.

Comment: You should know by now, that code relevant to your problem or question, always belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: _“I am under an impression that margin-right is used to push the object to which it is applied away?”_ - that is a very weird way of phrasing it. Margins are not used to “push elements away”, they are used to create _spacing_ between elements. _“In this case it is pushing the unrelated text away.”_ - the text is displayed _next_ to the floated list, so why would you call it “unrelated”? Them being next to each other, very much _is_ a “relation” to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Margin` property is not used for pushing the element it is applied to but if we take a box structure in which an element is placed, `margin` is used to keep a space around that 2d box from all edges , this space may be kept to distinguish this 2d box from the other 2d boxes lying on the webpage or if nothing is lying on the webpage, `margin` given to this 2d box may be used to show some space between edges of the webpage it is placed into.

Answer (score 2):

It gives a margin to the right of the element.
[image]

and since the element is aligned on the same "row", it'll push the element next to it, because the UL-element is on the same row as the p elements.

Answer (score 1):

> The margin area [create] an empty area used to **separate the element from its neighbors**.

From : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model